# How to get zipruby to native compile on Windows 7

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mingw

My apologies if this is a duplicate question.  I have inherited a project that contains ZipRuby as one of the required Gems.  My local development environment is Windows 7.  My ruby is 1.9.3p194.  I have Rails 3.2.6.  I have installed the RubyDevKit version 452.

All the other necessary gems either install or natively complile with no errors on Windows 7 but the ZipRuby gem.  I have never built a gem from scratch.  The gem starts to compile and gets the following errors.

```
`enter code here`        linking shared-object zipruby.so
        tmpfile.o: In function `zipruby_tmpnam':
        C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/tmpfile.c:56: undefined reference to `strcpy_s'
        C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/tmpfile.c:62: undefined reference to `_sopen_s'
       zipruby_archive.o: In function `zipruby_archive_read':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zipruby_archive.c:1447: undefined reference to `fopen_s'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zipruby_archive.c:1471: undefined reference to `_fclose_nolock'
       zip_close.o: In function `add_data':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:293: undefined reference to `ftello'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:312: undefined reference to `ftello'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:314: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:328: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       zip_close.o: In function `zip_close':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:188: undefined reference to `ftello'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_close.c:153: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       zip_crypt.o: In function `zip_crypt':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_crypt.c:293: undefined reference to `ftello'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_crypt.c:265: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       zip_dirent.o: In function `zip_cdir_write':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_dirent.c:109: undefined reference to `ftello'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_dirent.c:116: undefined reference to `ftello'
       zip_file_get_offset.o: In function `zip_file_get_offset':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_file_get_offset.c:64: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       zip_fopen_index.o: In function `zip_file_fillbuf':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_fopen_index.c:155: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_fopen_index.c:155: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       zip_open.o: In function `zip_checkcons':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:282: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       zip_open.o: In function `zip_open':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:84: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:85: undefined reference to `ftello'
       zip_open.o: In function `zip_find_central_dir':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:436: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       zip_open.o: In function `zip_readcdir':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:217: undefined reference to `fseeko'
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_open.c:220: undefined reference to `ftello'
       zip_source_filep.o: In function `read_file':
       C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\zipruby-0.3.6\ext/zip_source_filep.c:105: undefined reference to `fseeko'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status                                             make: *** [zipruby.so] Error 1
```

It is clear that references to one or more library files are not being resolved.  I am not sure where to go with this next.  Has anyone been successful in using zipruby with a mingw installation of ruby on Windows 7?

Some additional information I missed above.  To get this far, I had to install the windows development version of GnuWin32.  So the build command for the gem is: Gem install ZipRuby -- --with-opt-dir=Path.to.GnuWin32.folder.  This folder must have a lib and bin folder in it with source code.  I will update the question more if I learn more and post a solution if I figure out anything before I get an answer from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

try gem install zipruby --version "= 0.3.6" --platform=mswin32

It worked for me.